# How to sort an array in useSelector() without infinite rerendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-fullstack

I am trying to render a sorted list of anecdotes using `useSelector()` as part of Redux for [this](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part6/many_reducers#exercises-6-9-6-12) excercise in the course I am doing.

Every time I try to get the anecdotes from state I always get this error:
`Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.` which causes the app to infinitely rerender.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const anecdotes = useSelector(({ anecdotes }) => {
    return anecdotes.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.votes - a.votes
    })
  })
  const vote = (id) => {
    dispatch(voteAnecdote(id))
  }

  return(
    <div>
      {anecdotes.map(anecdote =>
        <Anecdote
          key={anecdote.id}
          anecdote={anecdote}
          handleClick={vote(anecdote.id)} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dispatching an action at each render, you must call `vote` only when you have a click:

Here is how to implement this (just create a function that call vote when the click is made):

```js
return(
    <div>
      {anecdotes.map(anecdote =>
        <Anecdote
          key={anecdote.id}
          anecdote={anecdote}
          handleClick={() => vote(anecdote.id)} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
```

Another note:

When you are using [`sort` you mutate the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in the state

Have you try this:

```js
  const anecdotes = useSelector(({ anecdotes }) => {
    return [...anecdotes].sort((a, b) => {
      return b.votes - a.votes
    })
  })
```

This will create a new reference for the array

Comment: Thank you so much! But instead I am now getting this error `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'` and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Fixed! I needed to change the useSelctor to this ` const anecdotes = useSelector(({ anecdotes }) => {
    return [...anecdotes].sort((a, b) => {
      return b.votes - a.votes
    })
  })`

Comment: Thanks 

I've updated the post with both recommandation

Answer (score 0):

Either keep it sorted in the store (sorting it before saving), or sort it after the `useSelector` call (It would have the same performance and effect as your current implementation, but without the rerenders)

Comment: When I do that I instead get this error `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'`

Comment: My assumption for the above error is that if you're trying to sort it directly, it would mean that you're trying to mutate the state object. You should instead make a copy of it, sort it, and then call `dispatch` on it. All outside the `useSelector` hook, of course.

Comment: Note that if you do the above, your state object will be updated to the new sorted array, and the next time you retrieve it elsewhere, it would remain sorted. If you don't want that to happen, you should probably consider Julien Code's answer below, which would just use a copy of the state object in the current component.